# ObjectAL audio streaming in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, streaming, pcm

I am using objectAL to stream PCM data,

from the sample code i have tried or play the online CGI streaming data,

```
   ALSource *source = [[ALSource source] retain];

   ALBuffer *buffer = [[[OpenALManager sharedInstance] bufferFromUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:[[OpenALManager sharedInstance]bufferAsyncFromUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someURL/somedata.cgi"] target:self selector:@selector(recievedBufferData:)]]] retain];

   source.position = alpoint(planet.position.x, planet.position.y, 0);
   source.referenceDistance = 50;
   [OpenALManager sharedInstance].currentContext.listener.position = alpoint(rocketShip.position.x, rocketShip.position.y, 0);

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
    [source play:buffer loop:YES];
}


-(void)recievedBufferData:(id)recievedData{
    NSLog(@"recieved");
}
```

I am getting the following error

OAL Error: -`[OALAudioFile initWithUrl:reduceToMono:]`: Could not open url some url/somefile.cgi (error code 0xffffffd5: Unknown ext audio error)

But The method recievedBufferData: is called only once

I cannot able to play the .cgi file, can anyone suggest me how to play the .cgi file in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying somethign similar, but not able to solve it.

Just wanted to ask, i think there is some error in the following line of code?:

```
ALBuffer *buffer = [[[OpenALManager sharedInstance] bufferFromUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:[[OpenALManager sharedInstance]bufferAsyncFromUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someURL/somedata.cgi"] target:self selector:@selector(recievedBufferData:)]]] retain];
```

Why are you calling bufferFromUrl and bufferAsyncFromUrl?

BTW i am able to make this work using a local file:

buffer = [[[OpenALManager sharedInstance] bufferFromFile:@"ColdFunk.caf"] retain];ng

Comment: Hi sunny, i need to load the audio data from remote url to ALBuffer class, and use it, the code you have provided is to load the audio file from local resource folder.